# exception while trying to use ignite-hibernate as l2 cache

Tags: ignite

Im getting this exception, while trying to use ignite-hibernate 2.1.1 as L2 cache with Hibernate 5.2.4

"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.ignite.cache.hibernate.HibernateEntityRegion$AccessStrategy.putFromLoad(Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Z)Z`"

jars used for this integration is

```
hibernate-core-5.2.4.Final.jar
ignite-core-2.1.1.jar
ignite-hibernate-core-2.1.1.jar
ignite-hibernate_5.1-2.1.1.jar
ignite-indexing-2.1.1.jar
ignite-log4j-2.1.1.jar
ignite-spring-2.1.1.jar
ignite-web-2.1.1.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

Apache Ignite provides integration with hibernate version 5.1.X. Unfortanually version 5.2.X is unsupported. Hibernate is based on Java 1.8 but Ignite support compatibility with ignite 1.7. For now I recomend you stay on 5.1.X version and check. Apache Ignite has plan on supporting new version, you can track status there:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5848